# Runtime implementation feature selection (Factory vs Shapeshifter struct)

Tags: rust

Imagine the following (common) task at hand: a cross-platform library is needed which provides access to physical devices (e.g. USB ones) and shall expose a unified API across all platforms. The following additional properties are to be satisfied:

- A platform can support multiple backends to interact with a physical device.
- The backend can be chosen by consumers of the library by using URIs.
- One must be able to choose the backend at runtime.

Here is the common implementation part representing two concrete USB device abstractions, "A" and "B":

```rust
// only available if feature "A" is selected
struct A {}

// only available if feature "B" is selected
struct B {}

trait Common {
    fn doit(&self);
}

impl Common for A {
    fn doit(&self) { /* do something */ }
}
impl Common for B {
    fn doit(&self) { /* do something */ }
}
```

The following is a naive example of using a global context struct as "factory" to solve the task:

```rust
struct Context {}

impl Context {
    pub fn create<S: AsRef<str>>(_uri: S) -> Option<Box<dyn Common>> {
        #[cfg(feature = "A")]
        if _uri == "A" {
            return Some(Box::new(A {}))
        }
        
        #[cfg(feature = "B")]
        if _uri == "B" {
            return Some(Box::new(B {}))
        }
        
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    // pretend feature "A" has been selected
    let a = Context::create("A");
}
```

But there is another way to do this in Rust - using a single struct which hides the implementation details but acts as a single point of contact to consumers:

```rust
struct Device {
    inner: Box<dyn Common>,
}

impl Device {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(_uri: S) -> Option<Self> {
        #[cfg(feature = "A")]
        if _uri == "A" {
            return Some(Device {
                inner: Box::new(A {})
            });
        }
        
        #[cfg(feature = "B")]
        if _uri == "B" {
            return Some(Device {
                inner: Box::new(B {})
            });
        }
        
        None
    }
}

impl Common for Device {
    fn doit(&self) { self.inner.doit() }
}

fn main() {
    // pretend feature "A" has been selected
    let a = Device::new("A");
}
```

Which one is deemed more idiomatic in Rust?
What about auto-derived traits such as `Send` or `Sync`?

For example, "A" and "B" being `Send` does not make `Box<dyn Common>` `Sync` automatically, instead one has to explicitly add the constraint: `Box<dyn Common + Send>`.
Adding such trait constraints in the first case (factory style) requires changing the function signature. In the second case, one only needs to change the internals of `struct Device`, the public facing API is not affected - apart from `struct Device` becoming e.g. `Send`.

Comment: How would that work? AFAIK using `impl Common` as return type in the signature means the compiler has to deduce the actual type at compile time - which is not possible here because `A` and `B` are two distinct types. Maybe I misunderstood though - can you show me a playground example?

Comment: Ah I missed the part where you have `cfg` at compile-time and `_uri` runtime checks.

Comment: I wouldn't consider any of the two approaches more idiomatic than the other -- I would just go with whatever suits your use case better.

Comment: You overlooked an additional possibility: a (non-exhausive) enum with a variant for each implementation, which can also be feature-gated (no real advantage over what you proposed, just another option). I'd personally lean toward the second option you proposed: it gives you flexibility to switch what's happening on the back-end without changing the interface, because everything can be wrapped up in the struct.